# how to implement a custom Abort-Button in a vaadin-upload 3.0.0 "Custom File List"

Tags: javascript, vaadin, shadow-dom, polymer-2.x

vaadin-upload 3.0.0 "Custom File List" still uses javascript code from vaadin-upload-file.html even though I provide my own HTML in the Shadow Root slot.

I'm not sure if this "works-as-designed", "is-a-bug" or I might not understand Shadow Root v1 slots.

I'm trying to customize a `vaadin-upload` with a "Custom File List" similar to as described here https://vaadin.com/elements/vaadin-upload/html-examples/upload-advanced-demos

```
<vaadin-upload id="fileEventsDemo" files="{{files}}">
  <div slot="file-list">
    <h4>Files</h4>
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{files}}" as="file">
        <li>
          <strong>[[file.name]]</strong>
          [[file.status]]
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</vaadin-upload>
```

According to my understanding of Shadow Root v1 this should replace the fallback content in `vaadin-upload.html`which uses a `<vaadin-upload-file>` element

```
<slot name="file-list">
  <div id="fileList" part="file-list">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[files]]" as="file">
      <vaadin-upload-file file="[[file]]"></vaadin-upload-file>
    </template>
  </div>
</slot>
```

So I assumed that `<vaadin-upload-file>` somehow disappears and I don't have to take care of it and only my HTML will be considered. I actually assumed that there never would be DOM instances of vaadin-upload-file at all. (Though it is imported `<link rel="import" href="vaadin-upload-file.html">` by  `vaadin-upload.html`)

But still I can set breakpoints in various JavaScript functions in `vaadin-upload-file.html` like `_formatProgressValue(progress)` or `_fileAborted(abort)` and they are called when the user interacts with the component.

This is especially tricky with `_fileAborted(abort)` which triggers a `file-remove` event. Because it will end up in this `vaadin-upload.html` method.

```
_removeFile(file) {
   this.splice('files', this.files.indexOf(file), 1);
}
```

When I try to implement my own file list `<my-file-list>` with a button to "Abort" (triggering a `file-abort` event) similar to the one in `vaadin-upload-list.html`

```
<vaadin-upload ...
    <div slot="file-list" id="fileList">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[files]]" as="file">
        <my-upload-file file="[[file]]"></my-upload-file>
      </template>
    </div>
</vaadin-upload>
```

then `this.splice('files', this.files.indexOf(file), 1);` is called multiple times. From my event from  as well as from  and indexOf might be negative.

Then multiple items are disappearing from the file list, not only the one that should be removed.

I'm using Ubuntu and Chrome Version 65.0.3311.3 (Official Build) dev (64-bit) for the debugging. The project uses Polymer 2.3.1 and vaadin-upload 3.0.0